# Another Nesting List comprehension?

Tags: python

In python, suppose I want to turn this list:

```
['EFJAJCOWSS', 'SDGKSRFDFF', 'ASRJDUSKLK', 'HEANDNDJWA', 'ANSDNCNEOP', 'PMSNFHHEJE', 'JEPQLYNXDL']
```

Into:

```
[['E', 'F', 'J', 'A', 'J', 'C', 'O', 'W', 'S', 'S'], ['S', 'D', 'G', 'K', 'S', 'R', 'F', 'D', 'F', 'F'], ['A', 'S', 'R', 'J', 'D', 'U', 'S', 'K', 'L', 'K'], ['H', 'E', 'A', 'N', 'D', 'N', 'D', 'J', 'W', 'A'], ['A', 'N', 'S', 'D', 'N', 'C', 'N', 'E', 'O', 'P'], ['P', 'M', 'S', 'N', 'F', 'H', 'H', 'E', 'J', 'E'], ['J', 'E', 'P', 'Q', 'L', 'Y', 'N', 'X', 'D', 'L']]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Calling `list` on a string gives you a list of characters.

So:

```
>>> data = ['EFJAJCOWSS', 'SDGKSRFDFF', 'ASRJDUSKLK', 'HEANDNDJWA', 
...         'ANSDNCNEOP', 'PMSNFHHEJE', 'JEPQLYNXDL']
>>> map(list, data)
[['E', 'F', 'J', 'A', 'J', 'C', 'O', 'W', 'S', 'S'],
 ['S', 'D', 'G', 'K', 'S', 'R', 'F', 'D', 'F', 'F'],
 ['A', 'S', 'R', 'J', 'D', 'U', 'S', 'K', 'L', 'K'], 
 ['H', 'E', 'A', 'N', 'D', 'N', 'D', 'J', 'W', 'A'],
 ['A', 'N', 'S', 'D', 'N', 'C', 'N', 'E', 'O', 'P'],
 ['P', 'M', 'S', 'N', 'F', 'H', 'H', 'E', 'J', 'E'],
 ['J', 'E', 'P', 'Q', 'L', 'Y', 'N', 'X', 'D', 'L']]
```

should work.

If you want this value in the variable `split` you can do:

```
split = map(list, data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension.

```
o = ['EFJAJCOWSS', 'SDGKSRFDFF', 'ASRJDUSKLK', 'HEANDNDJWA', 'ANSDNCNEOP', 'PMSNFHHEJE', 'JEPQLYNXDL']

split = [[c for c in i] for i in o]
```

Comment: Thanks I had tried [[ch for char in i] for i in o]; I almost had it!